# Geotools produces different GEOGCS value for ESRI WKT

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

ArcMap creates following contents in .prj file for WGS 84.

GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

While Geotools creates following when used ESRI citation, as per documentation: (http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/crs.html)

GEOGCS["WGS 84", DATUM["D_WGS_1984", SPHEROID["D_WGS_1984", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

Can anyone please tell me that why value of GEOGCS is appearing as "WGS 84" with geotools and not "GCS_WGS_1984". Because of this difference, ArcMap is not recognizing the projection.

Or is there any other way that I can create .prj file which will reflect  GCS_WGS_1984?

Geotools version: 13.5

Sample code:

```
Formattable f = (Formattable) CRS.decode("EPSG:" + epsg.getCode(), true);    
String wkt = f.toWKT(Citations.ESRI, 0);

CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.parseWKT(wkt);
```

Comment: Spheroid name is wrong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) uses the [OGC](http://opengeospatial.org) standard [EPSG](http://www.epsg.org/) [database](http://www.epsg.org/EPSGDataset/DownloadDataset.aspx) to determine the contents of the `.prj` file. The [WKT format standard](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/12-063r5/12-063r5.html) doesn't mandate any standard names for object in the CRS. So provided the actual parameters match, as they do in this case, the CRS are identical.

The ESRI formatter is primarily designed to put the entire WKT onto one line rather than rewrite elements in the CRS.

If you need to get an exact match I would use the ESRI code (ESRI:54001) - which from my quick scan of the [esri.properties](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/epsg-extension/src/main/resources/org/geotools/referencing/factory/epsg/esri.properties) file seems to be what you need.

Otherwise you could create a new definition file and use a new [FactoryUsingWKT](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/factory/epsg/FactoryUsingWKT.html) to read it and add it into your program.